# NullPointerException when running application

Tags: pointers, exception, null

Everytime I run or debug my application in java blackberry on simulator, I have a null pointer exception.
**Thread [net_rim_bb_feeds_lib(230)id=27277312] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))
ViewManager.insertTopLevelView(ViewImpl) line: 738**
I can't know the cause of the problem, could you please help me to solve this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing any code it might be difficult to help you.

Comment: The cause of the problem is obviously a null pointer. You basically have a null refrence which you are using for something (we can't tell a lot without a code snippet). You should debug line by line, and look out for where you have the null (this exception is a fundamental part of the programming learning curve IMO)

Comment: This sounds like a task for an IDE with a debugger!

Answer (score 0):

I clean the simulator and no more null pointer.
My problem is solved.